# Kotlin accessing asset from Fragment to set typeface

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to set typeface with custom font from my assets. In java is it simple as bellow

```
country2TextView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "open-sans-extrabold.ttf"));
```

I want to access `assets` from Fragment with this code bellow

```
country1TextView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.assets, "open-sans-extrabold.ttf")`)
```

But I got compiler error
`Only safe or non null assserted calls are allowed on a nullable receiver type of context`

How to access asset from fragment? Is it `good practice` if I just add safe call operator? or it is just workaround solution? What the best practice to access asset from fragment in Kotlin?

Answer (score 2):

There is a new way to doing this:

1. Put your_font.tff under **app/src/main/res/font**
2. Create Typefaces using:

```
    Typeface font = ResourcesCompat.getFont(requireContext(), R.font.your_font)
    yourTextView.setTypeface(font)
```

3. And to access font from XML layouts with:

```
    android:fontFamily="@font/your_font"
```

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions

1.)

```
country1TextView.setTypeface(
    Typeface.createFromAsset(country1TextView.context.assets, "open-sans-extrabold.ttf")))
```

2.)

```
val Fragment.requireContext get() = context!! 

country1TextView.setTypeface(
    Typeface.createFromAsset(requireContext.assets, "open-sans-extrabold.ttf")))
```

+1.) (technically same as 1.)

```
fun TextView.updateTypeface(typefaceName: String) {
    setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.assets, typefaceName)) 
} 

country1TextView.updateTypeface("open-sans-extrabold.ttf")
```

Please note that `createTypeface` is NOT a free operation below Android 6.0, so you should create typeface once and then use that.

Comment: Note that `requireContext()` as a method is already defined on `Fragment` so there's no need to define the extension yourself.

Comment: Ah. I always define a `requireActivity` and always mix them up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 country2TextView?.typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context?.assets, "open-sans-extrabold.ttf")
```

instead of this

```
country2TextView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "open-sans-extrabold.ttf"));
```

Comment: What difference with `country1TextView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context?.assets, "open-sans-extrabold.ttf"))` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    In Fragment always try to give context with respect to view
```

`country1TextView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(country1TextView.context.assets, "open-sans-extrabold.ttf")`)

or

```
        country1TextView.typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(country1TextView.context.assets, "open-sans-extrabold.ttf"))
```

`